# Find ID's not match a list

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I cannot say I am so experienced with SQL. Here is my question.
A table TripEvent have millions of rows. It contains a column Bold_ID that is indexed and unique.

So I can have this query

```
select bold_id from TripEvent where bold_id in (354469477, 354469536, 354469500, 987359)
```

Result is

```
354469477
354469536
354469500
```

as those exists. But I want to reverse it. How can I get a list if id's that don't exists ?
In this case it should return one row

```
987359
```

I cannot use NOT in query as that would return all rows in table not match my list.

Comment: SELECT bold_id FROM tripEvent Inner join list_of_values on tripEvent.bold_id = list_of_values.bold_id; I think if you had another table with all the values to compare that this would work.

Answer (score 1):

One way is like this:

```
SELECT DS.*
FROM
(
    VALUES (354469477)
          ,(354469536)
          ,(354469500)
          ,(987359)
) DS (bold_id)
LEFT JOIN TripEvent TE
    ON DS.[bold_id] = TE.[bold_id]
WHERE TE.[bold_id] IS NULL;
```

Of course, there are diff ways to populated the `DS`. I will recommend to populate the search IDs in a temporary table.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a SQL Server DB, you can use `EXCEPT`:

```
SELECT bold_id FROM
(
  SELECT 354469477 AS bold_id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 354469536
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 354469500
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 987359
) listofValues 
EXCEPT 
SELECT  bold_id
FROM  TripEvent;
```

OR:

```
SELECT bold_id FROM
(
  VALUES (354469477),
       (354469536),
       (354469500),
       (987359)
) listofValues(bold_id)
EXCEPT 
SELECT  bold_id
FROM  TripEvent;
```

Have a look in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Answer (score 0):

Found this query on another places. Seems to work. Thanks for the good response :)

```
  SELECT *
  from (values (354469477),(354469536),(354469500),(987359)) as v(id)
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT BOLD_ID FROM TripEvent WHERE TripEvent.BOLD_ID = v.id)
```

Comment: Yes, that's the implementation of what EXCEPT does. I think EXCEPT is better to read, but your query here has the advantge it will also do on other DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

```
select temp.* 
from (
        values 
             (354469477)
            ,(354469536) 
            ,(354469500) 
            ,(987359)
     ) temp (id) 
where 
        id not in
                  (
                     select 
                            bold_id 
                     from TripEvent
                  )
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?